# Convert string of array to standardized format

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

For my BigQuery table, I'm trying to convert this string of order data into a standardized format.

[Screenshot of string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeYLK.png)

Each curly brace represents an order item (i.e. variant) for the same order. I would like to generate an output like this where each row corresponds to an order item (the Order_ID is a separate field from the same table):

| Order_ID | Title | Variant | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ocean Plastic Deodorant | Sandalwood | 115 | 1 |
| 1 | Ocean Plastic Deodorant | Neutral | 115 | 3 |

How do I write the query?

Answer (score 0):

If we fully understand your question, the simple solution is to use JSON.parse()
[MDn json.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

You can also use this model online:

```
[{
  'id': 11894034792661, 
  'name': 'Ocean Plastic Deodorant - Sandalwood', 
  'price': '115.00', 
  'quantity': 1, 
  'product_id': 5661277356195, 
  'sku': '3', 
  'title': 'Ocean Plastic Deodorant', 
  'total_discount': '0.00', 
  'variant_id': 40944037101731, 
  'variant_title': 'Sandalwood'
 }, 
 {
  'id': 11894034825429, 
  'name': 'Ocean Plastic Deodorant - Neutral', 
  'price': '115.00', 
  'quantity': 3, 
  'product_id': 5661277356195, 
  'sku': '1', 
  'title': 'Ocean Plastic Deodorant', 
  'total_discount': '0.00', 
  'variant_id': 37101958693027, 
  'variant_title': 'Neutral'
 }]
```

[online-json-parse](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select json_query(json_entry ,'$.id') as id
    , json_query(json_entry, '$.name') as name
    , cast(replace(json_query(json_entry, '$.price'),'"','') as numeric) as price
    , json_query(json_entry, '$.quantity') as quantity
    , json_query(json_entry, '$.product_id') as product_id
    , json_query(json_entry, '$.sku') as sku
    , json_query(json_entry, '$.title') as title
    , cast(replace(json_query(json_entry, '$.total_discount'),'"','') as numeric) as total_discount
    , json_query(json_entry, '$.variant_id') as variant_id
    , json_query(json_entry, '$.variant_title') as variant_title
from unnest(
    (select json_query_array(json_data , '$') as elements
     from sample_data
     )
    ) json_entry
```

I'm not sure what you are referring to with the order ID, but if its in the same table you should be able to simply add it in to your select.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below option/approach

```
select * except(item) from (
  select order_id, key, value, item
  from your_table, 
  unnest(json_query_array(line_item , '$')) as item,
  unnest(`bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys`(item)) as key with offset
  join unnest(`bqutil.fn.json_extract_values`(item)) as value with offset 
  using (offset)
)
pivot (min(value) for lower(key) in ('title', 'variant_title', 'price', 'quantity'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]